# Can't spawn exe file after deploying electron app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I can't load the external exe file after deploying my electron app. it works well in development mode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtYbp.jpg)
this is how i call the external exe file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmW8s.jpg)
this is where my electron app is after deployment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHP47.jpg)
this is where the external exe file is (hogptestcli)

did i do anything wrong?

I tried different path names but it still doesn't work.